# jQuery and ajax to set session variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm using a session variable in PHP to manage the current language in a multi-language site. To achieve what I want I'm using a flag icon that when clicked (jQuery) it tells lang_json.php to switch the session variable to the new language.

I'm not getting errors on the jQuery side:

```
var sendData =  'en';  

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "lang_json.php",
    data: ({newLang: sendData}), 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (err){
      alert('Error');
    }
});
```

But the PHP file is not setting the session variable:

lang_json.php:

```
<?php

// Session variables
session_name('aklogin'); // Starting the session
session_start();

if( isset($_POST['newLang']) ){
    $_SESSION['current_lan'] = $_POST['newLang'];
}else{
    $_SESSION['current_lan'] = "Not Posting";
}

?>
```

The session variable is returning "Not Posting".

Comment: how are you testing that?

Comment: Can you try :    data: ({"newLang": sendData}),   With "newLang" in quotes? It looks like it's trying to use a variable there that doesn't exist. Is it not throwing an error in the JavaScript panel on that line of code?

Comment: No errors on the JavaScript panel.

Comment: I'm testing jQuery via via Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: It looks like the Json content type was throwing it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim you are sending the server JSON, but:

- You aren't
- The PHP isn't set up to receive JSON

Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`, then jQuery will set the correct content-type and PHP will populate `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing with the jQuery side and this is what worked:

```
var sendData =  'en'; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'app/pro/pro_lang_session_json.php',
    data: {'newLang': sendData}, 
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(sendData);
    },
    error: function (err){
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

The session variable sets to 'en' with this code.

Thank you for your help! @DelightedDOD