# Simple AJAX function to set SESSION variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I'm building a webpage in php, and want to change a $_SESSION variable from true to false on the click of a button.

I understand that php runs serverside, and as such I need to use AJAX to change that variable.

What I'd really like is a code to call an AJAX function (called methods in AJAX?) from a form button, the AJAX script then changes the SESSION variable. I'd really like to avoid page reload.

So, the form should look something like this:

```
<form action=ajaxMethod() method="get">
       <input type="submit" value="X" id="close">
</form>
```

And this is the php version of what I want the AJAX script to do:

```
function ajaxMethod() {
        $_SESSION["variable"] = false;
    }
```

However, I'm such a noob when it comes to JS, and especially AJAX, that I am unsure how to create that AJAX method.

As simple as possible... If simple is possible...

Any help?

Also: The page I'm building is propeitary and belongs to the company I'm working for, and as such I'm not at liberty to divulge the actual code, but the examples above feels like they describe what I'd like to accomplish. If needed, I'll explain further.

I'd love to avoid using JQuery, if at all possible.

Comment: [Getting started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I tried searching for "*php set session variable with ajax*" and found many questions here with working code to copy paste - did you try those?  A few examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894940/setting-php-session-variables-with-ajax, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985643/change-php-session-variable-using-ajax, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148408/setting-a-session-variable-in-php-using-ajax, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388188/jquery-and-ajax-to-set-session-variable-in-php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting PHP session variables with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894940/setting-php-session-variables-with-ajax)

Comment: Did a search but probably worded it wrong. Thanks so much for the hints, will take a look and see what I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding Jquery for your need/requirement is not possible since you don't want the page to reload, Ajax is best way for it (And Ajax is more simpler with JQuery).

I have used Ajax request in many of my php webApps to change `_SESSION` variables.

****HTML**:-**

```
<!-- Include Jquery library #Important -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<form>
       <input type="button" value="X" id="close" onclick="changeSession();">
</form>
```

**Script:-** {JQuery and Javascript both}

```
 function changeSession(){
        $.post("session.php",{ name : "session", value : "false"},
                function(data, status){ 
                     if(status == "success") console.log("successfully changed session variable"); 
                     else console.log("some error occurred");});
                        }
//Javascript
function changeSession(){
var value="false";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("post", "session.php"); 
    xmlHttp.send(value);//Don't know how to send multiple data with this sorry, so sending only 1
}
```

**PHP file :-** {session.php in my case}

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
      //I think we have received Ajax request
      if($_POST['value'] == "false") //Just to ensure the value to be changed should be false
      //Now let us change session variable
      $_SESSION['variable'] = "false";
}?>
```

**Points to remember:-**

1. You can make only 1 request to page at a time using Ajax.
2. The request can be either `POST` or `GET` at any time.
3. The variables you send from `$.post()` have to be properly handled at server side script {in my case `session.php`}.
4. You can also `echo` out text/html/json from php file as output of Ajax request.

Working Example [here](https://koding-khurram.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow/questions/68892054/)

**Note:-**

The code in working example may vary as I am trying to show how actually it works, however you can find the code in my Github, and for further queries comment below.

**Edit:-**

Added JavaScript code for Ajax request as you want to avoid JQuery. But didn't make a working example for it since I don't really prefer Ajax using JavaScript.

Comment: It's not AJAX I want to avoid, it's JQuery ;)
Appreciate your effort as it's taught me a lot in itself!

Comment: It's a simple AJAZ in my answer forget about JQuery there is nothing much, and believe me this is more simpler than `XMLHttpRequest` @4bZürd

Comment: You write that it's not possible to avoid pagerload without using jquery. But isn't JQuery jsut a framework that use inherent JS in a simpler way? And if so, shouldn't it be possible to rewrite the JQuery code to standard JS? Like I said in my original post: I'm a noob at this part of web development, so I need to ask stupid questions ;)

Comment: Edited the answer and added the `JavaScript code for Ajax request` as your need, but still I suggest you to learn at least Ajax in JQuery it's simple @4bZürd

Comment: Thank you again! I have definiteley been thinking about learning JQuery, I just haven't gotten around to it, and I don't feel comfortable using code I don't understand. But I take your encouragement to heart, and will start looking into JQuery as soon as I have time and opportunity.